# $HOME/.local/bin not in PATH for Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04

Was `$HOME/.local/bin` added to the PATH by default for Ubuntu 18.04?
I can't remember if it was, but I've just done a fresh installation of 19.04 and it definitely isn't.

The reason I ask is that `pip install --user` puts Python executables in `$HOME/.local/bin` so they won't work without additional configuration.

I wanted to know if there was some configuration step I missed before I start messing with my `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ah I see what's going on. It *is* added to the path by `$HOME/.profile` provided it exists, which it doesn't on a fresh install. `pip` creates it when it installs a package, but the `PATH` is not modified until `$HOME/.profile` is reloaded.

So the fix is either, after installing a `pip` package for the first time,

- `source ~/.profile`, or
- logout and log back in again.

Comment: I think you should self accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: I have run into this behaviour when creating a new user in Ubuntu 20.04.1.